# Oversized (higher resolution) virtual desktop by scaling/zooming out for Windows (XP)?

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop

Is there any virtual desktop for Windows (XP) which can emulate higher resolution by scaling/zooming out?

Answer (score 2):

There's a program called SDesk which I don't think is still in development but you can still find a download link from CNet.  It will let you create a desktop up to 32,000 x 32,000 pixels.

[SDesk Download](http://download.cnet.com/SDesk/3000-2346_4-10078754.html)

Comment: It was really hard to use.

Comment: Its very very very very very very difficult to use. please advise and instruct how to use it????????????????

Answer (score 0):

There is Infinite Screen tool:

http://ynea.futureware.at/cgi-bin/virtual_display_manager.pl

Does not limit virtual screen size
Allows looped virtual screen
Lets set windows' sizes larger than physical display size
Supports multi-display systems